# Clicking a http(s) link in Thunderbird does not open the link in the browser

Tags: thunderbird, hyperlink

Doubleclicking (or left-click + 'Open link in browser') of hyperlinks in Thunderbird does not work.
This has been going on for at least a year now, across many TB versions (currently 45.3.0).

- Clicking HTTP or HTTPS links from the browser, my PDF reader, MS Word, desktop shortcuts, whatever, all work.
- Opening mailto: links from TB works.
- The click does register: I see it briefly change color, but my browser does not start.

I have checked all things mentioned on the Mozilla support page [Hyperlinks in Messages Not Working](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/hyperlinks-in-messages-not-working):

- Default browser is set OK
- Actions for HTTP and HTTPS content types in Thunderbirds Tools > Options > Attachments > Incoming are set to 'Use Firefox (default)'
  There are no other 'suspicious entries'
- Under Help > Troubleshooting > Important Modified Preferences there are no entries for `network.protocol-handler.*`
  The config editor shows me that `network.protocol-handler.external-default` is set to default true
- Starting in Safe Mode does not help

I then did everything in [Standard diagnostics](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Standard_diagnostic_-_Thunderbird) that was possible:

- There was no `xul.mfl` file
- Deleted `localstore.rdf`
- Deleted the *extensions* folders (there was no *chrome* folder)
- Created a new profile, with MozBackup imported back into it: General settings, Emails, Address books, Bookmarks, Saved passwords, Certificates
- Removed the test profile, uninstalled TB, removed the TB directory, then reinstalled. It picked up my old profile.

Other things I tried:

- Martin Brinkmann's [Fix for Thunderbird not opening links](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/01/20/fix-for-thunderbird-not-opening-links/) of setting `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http` and `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https` to true, thereby forcing me once to pick the browser for opening links, did not help. No prompt came up, the link still did not 'execute'.
- I ran [Nirsofts FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html), The *open* settings for `.htm` and `.html` are FireFox. The command lines setting is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -osint -url "%1"`
  I reduced that in steps to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "%1"` without success

What else can I try?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the ghacks.net link. It worked for me on mac os high sierra + thunderbird 60.3.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more searching I found Ray K's suggestion in the mozilla.support.thunderbird Google Groups post [Clicking a link in Thunderbird won't open Firefox](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.thunderbird/BV_tAVu3gO4):

In Tool/Options/Attachments/Incoming, I changed the Actions for incoming HTTP and HTTPS content types from their default 'Use Firefox (default)' to explicitly picking `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla FireFox\firefox.exe` (it now says 'Use FireFox').

[image]
This solved the issue.

Comment: This answer solves my problem. In my case, I use a portable thunderbird and portable firefox, when I move those two from one PC to another, and their location is changed(such as from drive C in one PC, and now it becomes drive D in another PC), then double click on the link in the mail does nothing, not window opened, by follow this answer, I need to reselect the new location of the firefox, and now it works fine! Great!

Comment: This helped me too. Note that to make http and https appear in this Content Type list you may need to flip network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http(s) to make Thunderbird ask you once about what program to use.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Linux, however the "https" line did not appear in the "attachments" window. I had to manually modify the "handlers.json" file, which was located in the ".thunderbird" in my home folder.

Comment: This solved my problem too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue after a PC re-set and Thunderbird reinstall.
It worked again, for me, when I did NOT check the box

"Attach the source of this link to the message."

I hope this might be of help to others.
Thanks etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).